# a certain set of polynomials forming a subspace

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-spaces

Just out of curiosity:

Why is it that all polynomials vanishing on an irreducible component in some affine space form a vector subspace?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathbb{A}_k^n$ be affine $n$-space over some algebraically closed field $k$, and let $S\subseteq \mathbb{A}_k^n$ be any subset. Given $f,g\in k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, if $f(p)=0$ and $g(p)=0$ for all $p\in S$, then for any $a,b\in k$, 
$$(af+bg)(p)=af(p)+bg(p)=a\cdot0+b\cdot0=0.$$
Thus $I(S)$, the set of polynomials in $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ which vanish on $S$, forms a vector subspace of $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$. In fact, it forms an ideal, because for any $h\in k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$,
$$(hf)(p)=h(p)\cdot f(p)=h(p)\cdot 0=0.$$
When $S$ is an irreducible algebraic set in $\mathbb{A}_k^n$ (a.k.a. an algebraic variety), the ideal $I(S)$ is a prime ideal, and conversely as well.

Comment: Thanks Zev! So by what you did above, an irreducible component of scheme cannot be the union of finitely many proper subspaces.

Comment: I don't see how that's related. It is true that an irreducible scheme (in fact, disregarding the scheme structure, any irreducible topological space) cannot be the union of finitely many proper *closed* subspaces, which follows directly from the definition of "irreducible". But how does that follow from what I've written?

Comment: Well, you just proved that the functions vanishing on an irreducible variety form a vector space, and a vector space cannot be the union of finitely many proper subspaces. Do I need to add that we're working over the complexes?